# reuse mongodb connection and close it

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using the Node native client 1.4 in my application and I found something in the [document](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connection-pooling) a little bit confusing:

> A Connection Pool is a cache of database connections maintained by the driver so that connections can be re-used when new connections to the database are required. To reduce the number of connection pools created by your application, we recommend **calling MongoClient.connect once** and reusing the database variable returned by the callback:

Several questions come in mind when reading this:

1. Does it mean the db object also maintains the fail over feature provided by replica set? Which I thought should be the work of MongoClient (not sure about this but the C# driver document does say MongoClient maintains replica set stuff)
2. If I'm reusing the db object, when should I invoke the `db.close()` function? I saw the `db.close()` in every example. But shouldn't we keep it open if we want to reuse it?

**EDIT**:
As it's a topic about reusing, I'd also want to know how we can share the db in different functions/objects?
As the project grows bigger, I don't want to nest all the functions/objects in one big closure, but I also don't want to pass it to all the functions/objects.
What's a more elegant way to share it among the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of "connection pooling" for database connections has been around for some time. It really is a common sense approach as when you consider it, establishing a connection to a database every time you wish to issue a query is very costly and you don't want to be doing that with the additional overhead involved.

So the general principle is there that you have an object handle ( `db` reference in this case ) that essentially goes and checks for which "pooled" connection it can use, and possibly if the current "pool" is fully utilized then and create another ( or a few others ) connection up  to the pool limit in order to service the request.

The MongoClient class itself is just a constructor or "factory" type class whose purpose is to establish the connections and indeed the connection pool and return a handle to the database for later usage. So it is actually the connections created here that are managed for things such as replica set fail-over or possibly choosing another router instance from the available instances and generally handling the connections.

As such, the general practice in "long lived" applications is that "handle" is either globally available or able to be retrieved from an instance manager to give access to the available connections. This avoids the need to "establish" a new connection elsewhere in your code, which has already been stated as a costly operation.

You mention the "example" code which is often present through many such driver implementation manuals often or always calling `db.close`. But these are just examples and not intended as long running applications, and as such those examples tend to be "cycle complete" in that they show all of the "initialization", the "usage" of various methods, and finally the "cleanup" as the application exits.

Good application or ODM type implementations will typically have a way to setup connections, share the pool and then gracefully cleanup when the application finally exits. You might write your code just like "manual page" examples for small scripts, but for a larger long running application you are probably going to implement code to "clean up" your connections as your actual application exits.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed answer. I was assuming the NodeJS driver works the same way C# driver does. But it turns out it doesn't.  I'm actually working on a socket.io server project and I think it is what you call a "long running applications". So I get the db object ready before start listening in a port. And tried to share the same db among different requests. What you are saying is I need to do the clean up in some server events when the server exits, right? maybe `server.on("close", ...)`?

Comment: Another question is how should I share the db object? I'm trying to avoid passing it to different functions/objects. But I don't want to nest all the functions/objects in one closure either. Any suggestion how I can usually achieve this in a more graceful way?

Comment: @yaoxing Gaining access to that instance can be done in a number of ways without just placing all code within an "open" callback for instance. Sort of a broad question in itself, but consider a singleton class that holds the instance connection, and either poke around the Mongoose ODM code or even just use that and even schema-less if you want, as there are some techniques used there to share around the connection handle and pool used there. Remember that the "copies" are really just references unless you are explicitly cloning objects. So fairly cheap.